# Как правильно расположить элементы с помощью float: left;

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

На сайте имеется страница с превьюшками новостей. Все превьюшки выстраиваются в 2 колонки, имеют одну ширину, но разную высоту. Собственно разная высота мешает правильно расположить превьюшки в 2 колонки. Было бы легко, если бы колонки были фиксированной ширины, но ширина у них резиновая (50%).
Подскажите пожалуйста как решить проблему - [ссыль на фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/wRVpL/)

Comment: Забыл добавить, что из-за не фиксированной ширины, автоматически появляется не фиксированная высота, т.к. когда превтюшка "тянется" текст постоянно добавляет / убирает строки, из-за чего собственно меняется высота.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/142486/)** описано решение Вашей проблемы.

Удачи

---

Учитесь пользоваться поисковиком...

Comment: там описано интересное решение, но я пошел самым простым путем, написал скрипт, который после каждого второго блока вставляет еще один, с clear: left;
profit!

Comment: Да, это конечно вариант, но я думаю, что не стоит использовать JS там, где справится CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, Вам необходимо создать два класса: один c float:left, width:50%, второй с float:right, width:50%, а в них уже распологать Ваши контейнеры

Comment: С точки зрения серверного программирования это не подходит.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте после каждого второго эллемента ставить
    div style="clear:both" /div

Answer (score 0):

Обычно как-то наоборот: "wrapper" - "обертка". Соответственно сперва item-wrapper, внутри которого item. Ну да ладно...

Вариант с display: inline-block не катит?

получим что-то такое:

```
#container { 
}
.item {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    *display: inline;
    zoom:1;
}    
.item-wrap {
    outline: solid 1px black;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

В .item: inline и zoom - нужны только для IE7, поскольку последний не понимает inline-block. Как вариант можно вынести это в отдельный подключаемый css.

Дальше, есть тонкости. Если выполнить как есть, то колонки все равно не получатся. Дело в том, что inline-block заставляет элементы вести себя как строковые, то есть к ним применяется свойство white-space.

Решить проблему можно 4-мя способами.

1. не использовать разрывов:

   <div class="item">...</div><div class="item">...</div>

вместо

```
<div class="item">...</div>
<div class="item">...</div>
```

1. отрицательный маргин.

   .item {
       width: 50%;
       display: inline-block;
       vertical-align: top;
       *display: inline;
       zoom:1;
       margin: -1px;
   }
2. Задать нулевой размер шрифта контейнеру

   ## container{font-size: 0;}

и восстановить его в

```
.item {font-size: 12px;}
```

1. ну и последнее переопределить letter- и word-spacing у контейнера и восстановить его у item.

   ## container {

   ```
   letter-spacing: -.5em; 
   *letter-spacing: normal; 
   word-spacing: -.5em;
   ```

   }

   .item {
           width: 50%;
           display: inline-block;
           vertical-align: top;
           *display: inline;
           zoom:1;
           letter-spacing: normal;
           word-spacing: normal;
       }